# A value of type XFile cant be assigned to List<XFile>

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I want to Save a camera taken images to List to show Multiple Images in a GridView. but I can't Figure out how to do it.I want to add a XFile List to variable _imagesList

```
List<XFile> _imagesList=[];
void selectCamera(ImageSource imagesource,BuildContext cntxt) async {
    
    File cameraImages = await _picker.pickImage(source: imagesource); //error
    if(cameraImages!=null){
      _imagesList.addAll(cameraImages);

    }

    for(var img in _imagesList){
      final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();  
    final fileName = basename(img.path);    
    final savedImage = await File(img.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this- Hope it will help you. Mark correct if you find it helpful.

```
List<XFile> _imagesList=[];
void selectCamera(ImageSource imagesource,BuildContext cntxt) async {
    
   List<XFile> cameraImages = await _picker.pickImage(source: imagesource);
    if(cameraImages!=null){
      _imagesList.addAll(cameraImages);

    }

    for(var img in _imagesList){
      final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();  
    final fileName = basename(img.path);    
    final savedImage = await File(img.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
    }
    
  }
```